# is it useful to put HTML5 microformat in user access restricted pages

Tags: html, authorization, microformats

my question seems to be dumb, but because am making an application that *all* the pages needs to get the users authentification, and because am using **HTML5** so,

- Does Google robots parse those pages?
- if no, so then, is it useful to use **Microformats**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you are trying to do, but the question Microformats solve is "How can I make this HTML easily understandably by a computer?".

If you think that a computer will ever need to parse out the data in a meaningful way, then use it.

This could be either Google (though in your case, it won't be able to log in), an internal search you write at some point, a browser extension to highlight some sort of information etc.

In short though, it's unlikely to be useful, but on the other hand it's not hard to implement!

Comment: microformats as from what i've read is made to be speak a well understood language with a search engine, and this search engine cant enter to the page and got information, why then use it? (only the search engine case)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: microformats is not for search engines *only*. If *you* only care about *public* search engines and your site is not publicly accessible, then yes, there would be no use. But as Rich said, there are other use-cases.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/operator/ is an example of a browser extension that leverages µformats. They were meant to change the world, but browser implementation never really took off :(

Comment: now i get the idea, and because i've just made it for google and other public search engines, so i'll remove them since they're useless, thank you for your help